# How do I get WinSCP to connect to an SSH server with a private key that I specify?

Tags: ssh, winscp, private-key

How do I get WinSCP to connect to an SSH server with a private key that I specify.

I don't see the option.

[image: Screenshot]

- For example, I have a private key I created with SSH in cygwin. (id_rsa)

  ```
  $ ls ~/.ssh -l

    -rw------- 1 user None 2602 Dec 24 17:26 id_rsa
    -rw-r--r-- 1 user None  570 Dec 24 17:28 id_rsa.pub
    -rw-r--r-- 1 user None 4562 Apr 27 08:03 known_hosts

  $ cat .ssh/id_rsa

    -----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
    b3Blb...........wcm9ib29rMQECAw==
    -----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
  ```

  And I have already added the Public key (id_rsa.pub), to `authorized_keys` on the server.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On the WinSCP Login dialog, click the *Advanced* button, go to *SSH > Authentication*, and in the *Private key file* box, browse for your private key file:

[image: Screenshot]

See also https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login_authentication

---

If you do not have your key in the PuTTY `.ppk` format, you will need to change the file filter to *All private key files*; once you select the SSH key, WinSCP will offer to convert the key for you, saving a copy of the key in `.ppk` format.

Answer (score 0):

*(Martin's answer is quicker than this answer)*

The easiest way is to ensure you can connect in PuTTY first since it's very similar to WinSCP: [image: Screenshot1]

PuTTY requires the key to be a `.ppk` [Putty Private Key]

- How to [convert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhduJ.png) an RSA key (like OpenSSH uses) to a `.ppk` with PuTTYgen:

  1. *File* → *Load private key* → Change to show all files
  2. Choose `id_rsa` to load the RSA key → *File* → *Save private key*
- In PuTTY:

  1. *Connection* → *SSH* → *Auth* → *Private key file for authentication* → Choose the `.ppk`
  2. PuTTY asks you to specify the username, which is the same username as with OpenSSH [SSH used in cygwin when executing `ssh user@ip`]
  3. Now put PuTTY aside, as it helps to know how to connect with PuTTY

At the WinSCP login screen, go to *New Site* 
 [image: Screenshot]

1. *File protocol* → *SCP* [file transfer over SSH]
2. *Advanced* → *SSH* → *Authentication* → *Load private key* → Choose `.ppk` created above 
    [image: Screenshot2] 
    PuTTYgen is used to convert an RSA key to a `.ppk`, which is done in the same way I described above

Comment: This is unecessarilly complicated. WinSCP can convert the key for you. See my answer.